# get AJAX response with python

Tags: jquery, python, ajax

I have to make a POST request to a website using specific Header and Data to complete the operation properly , some of this data could be collected from the HTML code obtained with a GET request to the website.
(This is the problem) the rest of data is coming as Ajax not in the http header (I'm not familiar with this), I tried with requests module :

```
import requests
r=s.get(WebsiteLink,headers=header)
print r.headers
print r.history
```

and all what I get is just the HTTP header response .

I can see the data I need in the Firefox plugin : Live HTTP Headers  , Under Generator tab , I don't understand how , but it seems that Firefox is receiving the data as jQuery* (?) then sending the request with the proper Data , i didn't understood how I can receive them with python .

---

My header :

```
header={
'Host': ' www.mywebsite.com',
'User-Agent': " Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0",
'Accept': ' text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Language': ' en-US,en;q=0.5',
'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'Accept-Encoding': ' gzip, deflate',
'Referer': " https://mywebsite.com/",
'Cookie': ' My Cookies',
'Connection': ' keep-alive',
'Content-Type': ' application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}
```

Comment: It's difficult (i.e. impossible) for anyone to answer this question, as we don't see which URL you're calling, or the responses you're getting in Python, or the responses you're getting in Firefox. All we can do is make wild guesses at this point... You need to [edit] your question with more information, and preferably include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: ok thanks , i'll read more on ajax and jQuery before editing this

Comment: I don't see how AJAX and jQuery come into play here. You want to do this from Python, no?

Comment: yeah i mean at least get an idea on how the process goes .

Comment: Well, if you share the information I mentioned earlier perhaps people here can help you do so... Or you can go off and try and figure it out yourself ;-) Whatever you prefer.

Comment: this question explaining my exact problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35923566/how-browsers-get-facebook-dyn-and-ttstamp-parameters thanks for you're time .