# How browsers get facebook request parameters

Tags: jquery, python, facebook, python-requests

I'm creating a Facebook app with Python and I am stuck with this problem :

I need to understand how browsers get __dyn and ttstamp (parameters needed to make a POST request data for posting something on FB) since you can't find them on the Page's HTML.

When using Live HTTP Headers (Firefox plugin) or the Console you can find those parameters in the POST request.

When you track all the Requests made before that , you will find those parameters appeared for the first time in a URL in GET request with no parameters , how does Firefox get them? jQuery?

I have no experience in receiving jQuery responses with python, so if it's the case what's the best method to receive those parameters ? 
Here's what I tried :

```
import requests
r=s.get(FBlink,headers=header)
print r.headers
print r.history
```

All that I get is the HTTP header response.

Comment: If you want to interact with anything on Facebook – use their API.